# resque @queue variable returns nil during the test environment but within development it works

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

In development:

1.9.3p429 :001 > Auction::RiskProfile.instance_variable_get(:@queue)

=> :low_priority

1.9.3p429 :002 > Resque.queue_from_class(Auction::RiskProfile)

=> :low_priority

1.9.3p429 :003 > Resque.enqueue(Auction::RiskProfile)

=> true

But in test environment:

> Resque

=> Resque Client connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0

> Auction::RiskProfile.instance_variable_get(:@queue)

=> nil

> Resque.queue_from_class(Auction::RiskProfile)

=> false

> Resque.enqueue(Auction::RiskProfile)

Resque::NoQueueError: Jobs must be placed onto a queue.

from /home/bharani/Desktop/catawiki-bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.24.1

/lib/resque.rb:348:in `validate'

I don't know whats difference between development and test environments. please explain any one

Comment: Have you tried updating your `resque` gem? You have version 1.24.1, there is already version 2.0 and many problems similar to yours were fixed in follow-up versions.